# How can I make forked edges straight for single children in forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

[image]

here is my code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,tikz}
\newcommand{\equal}{=}
\begin{document}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            grow'=0,
            align=center,draw,
            fill=white, 
            blur shadow,
forked edges,
        },
%       forked edges,
        [Les branches \\ infinies
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f\left ( x \right ) \equal \pm \infty$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une asymptote verticale d'équation $x \equal a$]
        ]
        %
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f\left ( x \right ) \equal a$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une asymptote horizontale d'équation $y \equal a$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f\left ( x \right ) \equal \pm \infty$
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \frac{f\left ( x \right )}{x} \equal 0$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\ l'axe $\left ( \mathcal{O}x \right )$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \frac{f\left ( x \right )}{x} \equal \pm \infty$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\ l'axe $\left ( \mathcal{O}y \right )$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \frac{f\left ( x \right )}{x} \equal a $\\ avec $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f\left ( x \right ) -ax \equal \pm \infty$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\ la droite d'équation $y \equal ax$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f\left ( x \right ) -ax \equal b$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une asymptote oblique \\ d'équation $y \equal ax+b$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        ]
        ]
        [$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f\left ( x \right ) -\left ( ax+b \right ) \equal \pm \infty$
        [$\left ( \mathcal{C}_{f}\right )$ admet une asymptote oblique d'équation $y \equal ax+b$ au voisinage de $\pm \infty$]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't know why you received a downvote as your question is complete and appropriate in my opinion. Keep everything the same and add `anchor=center,` in `for tree = { ... }` to resolve the issue.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked

Comment: Welcome. I don't know if this is why this question was downvoted, but as a suggestion, a more descriptive title can be helpful to other users who may have a similar issue. For example, "How can I make forked edges straight for single children in forest?"

Comment: @SandyG - I've implemented your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to implementing [@M.AlJumaily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/167081/m-al-jumaily)'s suggestion, viz., adding the option `anchor=center` to the `for tree[...]` option list, I would alo suggest that you get rid of all -- yes, all! -- `\left` and `\right` sizing directives. They don't do anything useful, but they insert unwelcome whitespace, making an already fairly wide diagram even wider.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,
            %amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
            tikz}
\newcommand{\equal}{=}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow'=0,
        align=center,draw,
        fill=white, 
        blur shadow,
        forked edges,
        anchor=center % per suggestion of @M.AlJumaily
    },
    [Les branches \\ infinies
    [$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \equal \pm\infty$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une asymptote verticale 
     d'équation $x \equal a$]
    ]
    %
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) \equal a$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une asymptote horizontale 
     d'équation $y \equal a$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) \equal \pm\infty$
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \equal 0$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\ 
     l'axe $(\mathcal{O}x)$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \equal \pm\infty$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\  
      l'axe $(\mathcal{O}y)$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \equal a $\\ avec $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) -ax \equal \pm\infty$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une branche parabolique de direction \\ la droite d'équation $y \equal ax$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) -ax \equal b$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une asymptote oblique \\ d'équation $y \equal ax+b$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    [$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x) -(ax+b) \equal \pm\infty$
    [$(\mathcal{C}_{f})$ admet une asymptote oblique d'équation $y \equal ax+b$ au voisinage de $\pm\infty$]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```